# Search for specific situation in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a bot which needs to react to:

!bid [amount of keys]

But, when people write something like

Oh well, just use !bid.

It shouldnt count as a command. How do I check if comment.body is in this exact template. So when its being used as a sentence, it doesnt count.

Comment: use regular expressions of course, preferably after you clearly define the problem and make some effort to solve it yourself.

Comment: Regular expressions are completely unnecessary, and will only add to the complexity. Same case with agressiveness

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''this is a sentence with !bid [7.5] but this !bid doesn't count but !bid [12] does'''
```

You can use the pattern `'\!bid \[\d+\.?\d+?\]'` to find all instances of strings that match your criteria

```
>>> re.findall('\!bid \[\d+\.?\d+?\]', s)
['!bid [7.5]', '!bid [12]']
```

Or if you just want to extract the text between the `[]` you can use capture groups

```
>>> re.findall('\!bid \[(\d+\.?\d+?)\]', s)
['7.5', '12']
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just:

```
if comment.startswith('!bid'):
    command, rest = comment.split(' ', 1)
```

After that, `command == '!bid'` and `rest` is the rest of the line